# Python: Can't Import Module "flask-RESTPlus", when using Docker

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, flask-restplus

I have implemented a small Flask application by using a Docker environment.

This is my **project structure**:

```
dockertest
├─ .vscode
│  └─ settings.json
├─ compose_flask
   ├─ Dockerfile
   ├─ app.py
   ├─ docker-compose.yml
   └─ requirements.txt
```

This is the **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.8.0
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install Werkzeug==0.16.0
CMD python app.py
```

This is the **requirements.txt**:

```
flask-restplus
flask
redis
```

This is the **docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '2'
services:
    web:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        volumes:
            - .:/code
        depends_on:
            - redis
    redis:
        image: redis
```

And finally my **app.py**:

```
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis
from flask_restplus import fields, Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
redis = Redis(host='redis', port=6379)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    redis.incr('hits')
    print(redis.incr('hits'))
    return 'This Compose/Flask demo has been viewed %s time(s).' % redis.get('hits')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

The build with the command: `build -t compose-flask:latest .` works just fine!
When I try to start the container with `docker-compose up`, the following Error Message appears:

```
redis_1  | 1:M 10 Mar 2020 23:10:05.011 * Ready to accept connections
web_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1    |   File "app.py", line 4, in <module>
web_1    |     from flask_restplus import fields, Api, Resource
web_1    | ImportError: No module named flask_restplus
compose_flask_web_1 exited with code 1
```

Seems like Python is not able to find the flask-RESTPlus package? The console output of the build tells me, that flask-RESTPlus has been successfully installed.
The strange thing is that the same example without Docker works just fine without any import errors!!

I can't figure out what the problem is...
I would be glad if someone could help!

Comment: I tried to run your files and it works for me. Maybe you can try to run `docker-compose down -v` before running `docker-compose up` again?

Comment: That's solved the problem! Thanks!